Is there a tool or setting I can enable on expo to browse the app's document directory in Android
In Expo iOS I can do
      "infoPlist": {
        "UISupportsDocumentBrowser": true,
        "UIFileSharingEnabled": false,
        "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace": false
      }

which will allow me to browse through the contents of the FileSystem.documentDirectory of the app using the Files app.
I am trying to see if there's an equivalent way of doing that on Android, which does have a files app but it does not appear to have a way to map to an app's document directory
